# How to display inputs of a function in an ordered list

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, for-loop

I need to make a code that creates a form, having three interests. When the usere submits them, they need to appear in a list. So far, i have this coding:

When I click on "submit" i do not get directed anywhere though.

```
<html>
   <head>
    <script>
function validateForm()
{var x=document.forms["myForm"]["interest1"].value;
var y=document.forms["myForm"]["interest2"].value;
var z=document.forms["myForm"]["interest3"].value;

}
</head>
    </script>

    <body>
      <form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit=return validateForm()" method="post">
        Interest 1:<input type="text"  name="interest1">
        Interest 2:<input type="text" name="interest2">
        Interest 3:<input type="text" name="interest3">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

i need to use a for loop for getting the submitted values. How do I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the validateForm function? right now you are just assigning values to variables which you don't use.

Comment: Also, you are missing a quote at the start of your onsubmit attribute.

Comment: Your </script> tag is misplaced (after the </head> end-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're returning the function on submit, try returning true from your function if you want to submit

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["interest1"].value;
    var y=document.forms["myForm"]["interest2"].value;
    var z=document.forms["myForm"]["interest3"].value;

    // TODO: validate x, y and z

    return true;
}
</script>
```

Your closing tags are ordered incorrectly also, make sure `</script>` occurs before `</head>`.